# how to use css3 transitions with jquery animate?

Tags: jquery, css, transform, jquery-animate

i have this carousel from [here](http://www.bkosborne.com/jquery-feature-carousel) and i am trying to add some css3 transform options to it.

more exactly:

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg);
```

in the javascript i have

```
if (newPosition == 1) {
    new_width = pluginData.largeFeatureWidth;
    new_height = pluginData.largeFeatureHeight;
    new_top = options.topPadding;
    new_zindex = $feature.css("z-index");
    new_fade = 1.0;
  } else {
    new_width = pluginData.smallFeatureWidth;
    new_height = pluginData.smallFeatureHeight;
    new_top = options.smallFeatureOffset + options.topPadding;
    new_zindex = 1;
    new_fade = 0.4;
  }
```

and the animate function runs here

```
 .animate(
      {
        width: new_width,
        height: new_height,
        top: new_top,
        left: new_left,
        opacity: new_fade
      }
```

the generated css is:

```
element.style {
    width: 225px;
    height: 115px;
    top: 70px;
    left: 50px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

now, all this vars are being calculated by this plugin, and i am only interested in adding the transform options to this animate function, something like this:

```
....
} else {
    new_width = pluginData.smallFeatureWidth;
    new_height = pluginData.smallFeatureHeight;
    new_top = options.smallFeatureOffset + options.topPadding;
    new_zindex = 1;
    new_fade = 0.4;
    new_transform_style = 'preserve-3d';
    new_transform = 'rotateY(45deg)';
}
```

and

```
.animate(
      {
        width: new_width,
        height: new_height,
        top: new_top,
        left: new_left,
        opacity: new_fade,
        transform_style = new_transform_style;
        transform = new_transform;
      }
```

but im not sure that those are the right style notations for animate

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: The jQuery Animation library is not powered by CSS3 transforms, it's strictly JavaScript-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't animate rotation/scale in jQuery by default.

But there is a plugin which fixes this:

[Animate Rotation and Scale in CSS](http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/08/07/jquery-animate-css-rotate-scale.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom property with `.animate()` and perform the transformation "manually" using the step function.

See [this SO answer of me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21815901/490560) for more details.